# Report Type question

Tags: reporting

Along with some standard report types, I noticed that when creating custom objects and relationship fields, Salesforce will automatically create some report types with the word AND

e.g  Opportunities with Team and Products.
     Leads and Connections.
     Contracts with orders and Products

Question.  Is there any documentation around this?  I ask because most documentation is around with or without relationships.  Is the Custom Report Type equivalent adding a field via a lookup in CRTs?  What is the significance?  Thanks

Thanks in advance

Comment: your surmise is basically correct although there are some standard report types that can't be replicated with Custom Report Types

Comment: @cropredy any chance you could answer the details around the automation relating to object creation and relationship fields? (e.g. if i create an object 1 and set it's master detail to object 2, what "standard" report types are created). i asked this previously http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42194/what-is-the-logic-for-the-automatic-creation-and-update-of-custom-report-types?rq=1

Comment: thing that is throwing me off, is in some cases the "standard" report type is created automatically, but in others it seems to get skipped. personally i'm hoping to understand this so i can use the "standard" reports more often as they don't require maintaining the included fields the way "custom" report types do

Comment: to narrowly answer `Is the Custom Report Type equivalent adding a field via a lookup in CRTs? ` - the answer is YES